# Android WebView crashing with latest Chrome 81.x update specially on Android 9.x

Tags: android, webview, chromium

Last few days we are seeing lot of report from our users that our app (which uses webview) is crashing after their device got the Chrome v 81.x update.

IN Play Store Crashes report I am seeing following messages :

**pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.xxx.yyy<<<
backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000015facb4  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-x68QXO8NOOB36W-KEnFfCg==/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so**

**backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000237a354  /data/app/com.android.chrome-kyBxfoIez_ogh7zita-a1A==/base.apk (offset 0xc3b000)**

If user revert back to older version of chrome, it works fine. Has anyone else experience this? We have not made any changes recently so seems to be related to Chrome update only. 
The Chrome version update is not visible in Play Store so we could not test but we found the apk from apk mirror and were able to replicate on Android 9 Emulator 
with  Google Play Services
com.android.chrome_81.0.4044.111. 
Stack Trace Below

```
    2020-04-17 00:10:47.429 14092-14092/com.xxx.yyyE/WebViewFactory: error instantiating provider
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:265)
       at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2681)
       at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2676)
       at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2741)
       at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4807)
       at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4948)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:659)
       at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:55)
       at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:659)
       at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:626)
       at com.xxx.yyy.ui.components.CustomWebView.<init>(CustomWebView.java:86)
       at com.xxx.yyy.ui.components.CustomWebView.<init>(CustomWebView.java:80)
       at com.xxx.yyy.ui.fragments.BaseWebViewFragment.createWebView(BaseWebViewFragment.java:171)
       at com.xxx.yyy.ui.fragments.BaseWebViewFragment.init(BaseWebViewFragment.java:86)
       at com.xxx.yyy.ui.fragments.TabletWebViewFragment.init(TabletWebViewFragment.java:36)
       at com.xxx.yyy.ui.managers.TabletUIManager.addTab(TabletUIManager.java:250)
       at com.xxx.yyy.ui.managers.BaseUIManager.addTab(BaseUIManager.java:209)
       at com.xxx.yyy.ui.managers.BaseUIManager.onNewIntent(BaseUIManager.java:412)
       at com.xxx.yyy.ui.activities.BrowserActivity.onCreate(BrowserActivity.java:423)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
```

Any help/pointer will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I see the same issue. But I could not reproduce the problem on the emulator. Does this problem still occur in the latest chrome (81.0.4044.138)?

Comment: Happens to me too, though rarely.

Comment: Hi, We found the issue was related to the logic in the app where we were capturing website thumbnail to display bookmarks. Once we removed that code to use favicons, it solved the issue.  Something in Chrome got changed in latest version (81.0.4044.138) that lead to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue was related to the logic in the app where we were capturing website thumbnail to display bookmarks. Once we removed that code to use favicons, it solved the issue. Something in Chrome got changed in latest version (81.0.4044.138) that lead to this issue. – user899849 just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: Thank you for the information. Have you tested Chrome beta (83 version)? You can select beta verion in the 'Webview implementation' of the 'Developer options' after installation. I have reported a similar issue on the Chromium Issue Tracker. But I could not reproduce the problem and could not give the crash id to them. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1081690 If you still have the problem, please let them know the crash id.